# App store submission: Priority Update?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

My new boss thinks you can submit an update to app Store and mark it as priority once or twice a year. if your abuse it you lose your privilege?

Is he correct. I've been submitting updates for years and never heard of it?

cheers

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can request a Expedited review, which should be used if you've submitted an app which has been approved but it has an issue that needs to be fixed urgently. As your boss has said they can only be done a few times so be cautious doing them.

> Expedited reviews are granted on a limited basis so we cannot guarantee that every request will be expedited.

http://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/appreviewteam/

Answer (score 1):

Got app reviewed in one day...grudgingly (see email).... Dear APPLE HIRE MORE REVIEWERS!!!!!

---

Hello .....,

Thank you for contacting the App Review Team.

We understand that situations arise which require an exceptional response, however, we have received multiple expedite requests from  .... within a short period of time.

We have made an additional exception for your app and will proceed with an expedited review. We wanted to remind you, however, that expedited reviews are provided on a limited basis, otherwise the process itself becomes ineffective. Please keep in mind that we may not be able to accommodate additional requests in the future.

If your app is rejected during this review, it is not necessary to request another Expedited Review when you resubmit. Once you revise and resubmit your binary (or metadata, in the case of a Metadata Rejection), your app will be automatically returned to the expedite queue.

Best Regards,

App Review Team

Comment: To be fair, it's not up to apple to hire more reviewers to account for poor submissions, 7 days is a good turn around time. The onus is on you to ensure your code is working correctly and as they state you have submitted multiple expedite requests, which indicates you regularly submit poor quality code

Comment: `your app will be automatically returned to the expedite queue.` it's useful